# AutoComplete Textbox with database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I wanna do autocomplete when i enter a letter.
I have a database "USERS" and  it has name .When i try texted for example e 
it must show "edgar,edwin,emir" but ,t shows nothing.
ClientController here:

```
 public class ClientController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string searchstring)
    {
        ModelContext  db = new ModelContext();

        var suggestions = from E in db.USERS
                          select E.Name;


        var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToLower().Contains(searchstring.ToLower()));

        return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

index.cshtml here:in here there is a textbox and i send client controller autocopleteSuggeston method but it doesnt go or it doesnt work.I add jquery script file on cshtml but it still not working.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <p>
        Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery(function () {
        window.jQuery("#SearchString").autocomplete({
            source: "/Client/AutocompleteSuggestions",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    window.jQuery("#SearchString").val(ui.item.value);
                    window.jQuery("form").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

i add jquery 
Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add [HttpPost] before JsonResult method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string searchstring)
{
    ModelContext  db = new ModelContext();

    var suggestions = from E in db.USERS
                      select E.Name;


    var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToLower().Contains(searchstring.ToLower()));

    return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

as the form here is submitted using **window.jQuery("form").submit()**,it invokes a Post Action, so you need to add [HttpPost] for capturing the form submissions or any kind of Post Action!

**Change your View Code to**

```html
 @using( Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new{@id ="SearchForm"} ))
{

    <p>
        Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

```
$(function() {
$("#SearchString").autocomplete({
    source: "/Client/AutocompleteSuggestions",
    select: function(event, ui) { 
         $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.value);
         $("#SearchForm").submit();
     }
});
});
```

Comment: does it hit the controller??

Comment: i dont think so @psylogic

Comment: is the jqury function called? give me something,where exactly the issue rises??

Comment: There is no mistake while compling but it doesnt work after starting

Comment: did you even try to debug the code??? you can not just paste the code here and say its not working ! debug it and tell me where exactly the code fails to execute.

Comment: Jquery doesnt work.I dont hit AutocompleteSuggestions methods

Comment: Have you added all the necessary libraries and referenced them in your View??If not then do that and see weather the jquery is called.

Comment: i added all of them and referenced in view but still not working.@psylogic

Comment: OK the reason its not working is you haven't put in any effort to solve this problem, you just say it doesn't work. YOU haven't even tried to debug the code and find out where exactly the issues rises, I'm sorry but I can't help you anymore Sorry!

Comment: i did it . i have to add "@section scripts{}" and remove [HTTPPOST].Thank you @psylogic

Comment: good to know and you are welcome though i did not solve the issue, but i wonder how does it work without [Httppost ] when you are submitting the form?

Comment: i think i don't submit button.when f.e=>i click e letter England directly come.Not submit button.Button is for showing all records which starts with this letter.@psylogic

Comment: not the submit button but ** window.jQuery("form").submit();** will definitely submit the form